# What does this expression mean in this context? 見た目通りのおっとり系 (A character is describing his bro-con big sister)

Tags: meaning, expressions, suffixes

When reading, I encountered this expression and do not quite understand. My guess is: "She is very gentle (?) like her appearance."

The conversation:

> Mc's Big Sister: 「ああ～　生き返りますそーちゃん、そーちゃん会いたかった～。昨日の夜ぶりだね、会いたかったよぉ～」
> 二本木家次女、僕の二番目のお姉ちゃんこと二本木日和は**見た目通りのおっとり系だ。**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your question is mainly about おっとり.

[A dictionary definition](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%8A%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A8%E3%82%8A/#jn-31745) as follows:

> 人柄・しぐさなどが、落ち着いていてこせこせとしないさま。おおようなさま。「―（と）構える」「良家の出らしい―した振る舞い」

Taken positively, it means *calm, non-hectic, generous, soft*.  Sometimes it could be used somewhat negatively meaning *slow, non-responsive*. Opposite characteristics I can think of are *eager, aggressive, restless* etc.

As for 通り and 系, see the following:

- [What exactly does この通り mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/4913/45489)
- [Defining a particular 系](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4572/defining-a-particular-%E7%B3%BB)

Overall, the phrase means *She is a soft-type as her appearance suggests.*